# With an Inner Join between just two tables, having trouble filtering a "right" database column

Tags: filter

So say code=

```
select toy category, count(customerstate)
from toyinventory ti
INNER JOIN toyorders to
ON ti.orderid = to.orderid
where ti.plantid = 31-12-2020
and ti.category = 'dolls'
group by customerstate'
```

ok so filtering date and category which are columns in toyinventory  but how to filter something from toyorders like say to.dolltype <> 'barbie' ?  THX

getting cannot be bound error when i tried this as another and
getting bad data when i tried this as and after ON

Comment: rather, plantid= "CA"  (not any date).  If I had say 5 filters for ti, and wanted just one for to, how to do ?  Tried that just under ON but did not work. Tried it as a regular and, identified as to.dolltype <> 'barbie' and did not work either.  THX

Comment: OK  How about this... may be that there is a quirk in the following exclusion:

Comment: and not Toyorder_completion  = ('* Completion > 90%*')

Comment: its just not filtering this out